# Вывести все пары из таблиц

Tags: sql

Имеются 3 таблицы

```
People             Sex                 Marriages

+--+----+------+   +------+--------+   +------------+-------------+
|ID|name|sex_ID|   |sex_ID|sex_name|   |First_man_ID|Second_man_ID|
+--+----+------+   +------+--------+   +------------+-------------+
|1 |Ola | 2    |   | 1    | M      |   | 1          | 2           |
|2 |Gena| 1    |   | 2    | F      |   | 1          | 3           |
|3 |Yura| 1    |   | Null | Null   |   | Null       | Null        |
+--+----+------+   +------+--------+   +------------+-------------+
```

Как составить SQL запрос, чтобы выбрать все связанные между собой пары, т.е. в зависимости от значений таблицы `Marriages` сопоставить имена между собой.

В нашем случае это будет :

```
+-----+------+---------+----------+
|First|Second|First_sex|Second_sex|
+-----+------+---------+----------+ 
|Ola  | Gena | F       | M        |
|Ola  | Yura | F       | M        |
+-----+------+---------+----------+
```

P.S. Не заостряйте внимания на положении Оли)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select p1.name as First,
       p2.name as Second,
       s1.sex_name as First_sex,
       s2.sex_name as Second_sex
from Marriages m
left join People p1 on p1. id = m.First_man_ID
left join People p2 on p2. id = m.Second_man_ID
left join Sex s1 on s1.sex_ID = p1.sex_ID
left join Sex s2 on s2.sex_ID = p2.sex_ID
where m.First_man_ID is not null
```

Comment: `where m.First_man_ID is not null` - если нужны строго ***пары***, то нужно оба поля проверить на NOT NULL, наверное...